# Script Error in Internet Explorer only when using arrow functions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a function that contains an arrow function. It works fine in Edge, Chrome, FireFox but when ever I try to run it in Internet Explorer 10 && 11 i get a syntax error.

Is there any way of doing this that will support Internet Explorer, or another work around?

```
function range(start, end) {
    return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start);
}
```

the syntax error appears to be at the "=>"

Comment: try to change range function to array function as `const range =  (start, end)  => { ... }`.

Comment: There is no LINQ here - this is completely misleading. LINQ is a .NET construct and doesn't exist in JavaScript (unless you use a library). I've corrected the terminology for you to focus on the real problem. And the issue is that IE doesn't support arrow functions. See [Syntax error in IE using ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40110022) and [Equivalent of arrow functions for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50241267). Note that even if the arrow function is fixed [IE also doesn't support `Array.from`](https://caniuse.com/#search=Array.from) - that's the next error you'd get.

Comment: @micronyks how would that help anything?

Comment: See also [Alternative or polyfill for Array.from on the Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36810940). However arrow functions and `Array.from` are only two issues, IE is going to have *many* as it doesn't support the majority of ES6+ standards and it never will. You're better off using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for ES6 in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902809/support-for-es6-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: Is there any way to change the return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start) into for loop

Answer (score 0):

As other community members had already informed you that **Array.From** and => **Arrow functions** are not supported in the IE browser.

For **Array.From** there is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) available. you can try to use it for the IE browser.

Code:

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 6, 22.1.2.1
if (!Array.from) {
    Array.from = (function () {
        var symbolIterator;
        try {
            symbolIterator = Symbol.iterator
                ? Symbol.iterator
                : 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)';
        } catch {
            symbolIterator = 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)';
        }

        var toStr = Object.prototype.toString;
        var isCallable = function (fn) {
            return (
                typeof fn === 'function' ||
                toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]'
            );
        };
        var toInteger = function (value) {
            var number = Number(value);
            if (isNaN(number)) return 0;
            if (number === 0 || !isFinite(number)) return number;
            return (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(number));
        };
        var maxSafeInteger = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;
        var toLength = function (value) {
            var len = toInteger(value);
            return Math.min(Math.max(len, 0), maxSafeInteger);
        };

        var setGetItemHandler = function setGetItemHandler(isIterator, items) {
            var iterator = isIterator && items[symbolIterator]();
            return function getItem(k) {
                return isIterator ? iterator.next() : items[k];
            };
        };

        var getArray = function getArray(
            T,
            A,
            len,
            getItem,
            isIterator,
            mapFn
        ) {
            // 16. Let k be 0.
            var k = 0;

            // 17. Repeat, while k < len… or while iterator is done (also steps a - h)
            while (k < len || isIterator) {
                var item = getItem(k);
                var kValue = isIterator ? item.value : item;

                if (isIterator && item.done) {
                    return A;
                } else {
                    if (mapFn) {
                        A[k] =
                            typeof T === 'undefined'
                                ? mapFn(kValue, k)
                                : mapFn.call(T, kValue, k);
                    } else {
                        A[k] = kValue;
                    }
                }
                k += 1;
            }

            if (isIterator) {
                throw new TypeError(
                    'Array.from: provided arrayLike or iterator has length more then 2 ** 52 - 1'
                );
            } else {
                A.length = len;
            }

            return A;
        };

        // The length property of the from method is 1.
        return function from(arrayLikeOrIterator /*, mapFn, thisArg */) {
            // 1. Let C be the this value.
            var C = this;

            // 2. Let items be ToObject(arrayLikeOrIterator).
            var items = Object(arrayLikeOrIterator);
            var isIterator = isCallable(items[symbolIterator]);

            // 3. ReturnIfAbrupt(items).
            if (arrayLikeOrIterator == null && !isIterator) {
                throw new TypeError(
                    'Array.from requires an array-like object or iterator - not null or undefined'
                );
            }

            // 4. If mapfn is undefined, then let mapping be false.
            var mapFn = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void undefined;
            var T;
            if (typeof mapFn !== 'undefined') {
                // 5. else
                // 5. a If IsCallable(mapfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
                if (!isCallable(mapFn)) {
                    throw new TypeError(
                        'Array.from: when provided, the second argument must be a function'
                    );
                }

                // 5. b. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
                if (arguments.length > 2) {
                    T = arguments[2];
                }
            }

            // 10. Let lenValue be Get(items, "length").
            // 11. Let len be ToLength(lenValue).
            var len = toLength(items.length);

            // 13. If IsConstructor(C) is true, then
            // 13. a. Let A be the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method
            // of C with an argument list containing the single item len.
            // 14. a. Else, Let A be ArrayCreate(len).
            var A = isCallable(C) ? Object(new C(len)) : new Array(len);

            return getArray(
                T,
                A,
                len,
                setGetItemHandler(isIterator, items),
                isIterator,
                mapFn
            );
        };
    })();
}
```

for => [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) I suggest try to use the [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your ES6 code to Es5 code. After that, it will work with the IE browser.